# Who understood Daenerys' speech?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dialogue

In *Game of Thrones* S08E06, Daenerys gave a speech to her Unsullied and Dothraki troops where she said

> that she was going continue on her campaign of "liberation" to Winterfell and Lannisport, i.e. kill everyone in and burn down the homes, of Jon and Tyrion respectively.

Other than the troops, who of the listeners would have understood what she was saying?

Comment: ...I thought this question was going to be about the speech from a practical standpoint.  She was speaking slightly louder than normal, to a crowd ...half a mile or so away? And they all understood every word? That was what I was wondering the whole time - *how* could they hear her?

Comment: They've been doing that for the entire series. I've always just considered it artistic license.

Comment: I think you can see Jon react a bit when he hears her mention Winterfell. I guess he doesn't understand what she's saying about it, but can get the gist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we see from the episode, there's:

- The Unsullied
- the Dothraki
- Jon Snow
- Tyrion Lannister
- Arya Stark
- Northmen

We know that the Unsullied and the Dothraki understand her.

Tyrion has at least some knowledge of what she is saying.

Jon and Arya don't. And in the show there's no indication that they understand another language besides the common tongue.

Comment: Jon did respond when Dany said "Winterfell" (followed by other placenames). Based on people's reactions and Dany's tone, he could infer some things though. But yes, he did not understand the language itself.

Comment: On 'Tyrion has at least some knowledge of what she is saying' was brought up in the conversation with Jon while Tyrion was captive.